# Rashi to Yirmeyahu 52:25

Tags: rashi, translation, yirmiyahu--book-of

How do you translate this Rashi:

בספר מלכים אמר וחמשה אנשים (מלכים ב כ״ה:י״ט) השנים חשובים ולא חשובים כ״כ

Comment: What is the specific problem that you have with the text?

Comment: @TamirEvan don't have a problem just don't read hebrew too well.  to my mind it says "in the book of melachim it says 'and 5 men.'  The repeated are important but not that important."  But my "translation" of course doesn't make sense so I would like someone to translate it better.

Comment: That information should be in the question itself, to help answerers better understand what you want/need.

Comment: @TamirEvan the question couldn't be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome johntessler.

As a note of preface, the wording of **Yirmiyahu perek 52** is very similar to the wording of **Melachim II perek 25** as both deal with the **events of the destruction of the first temple** (*see a sample comparison of highlighted differences in the following image*).
[image]

There are a number of discrepancies in the otherwise similar wording and Rashi is coming to explain the difference between:

- **Yirmiyahu 52:25**

> **ושבעה** אנשים מראי פני המלך - and **seven** men from those who regularly saw
> the face of the king (ie. men of importance)

AND

- **Melachim II 25:19**

> **וחמשה** אנשים מראי פני המלך - and **five** men..........

Rashi explains that: (*words in parentheses are added by me for explanation*)

> בספר מלכים אמר "**וחמשה** אנשים". **השנים** חשובים ולא חשובים כ״כ

> In the book of Melachim it says "**five** men" (*leaving a
> discrepancy of two*). The **two** (*extra mentioned in Yirmiyahu*) were of
> importance but not so important (*as the other five*).

Comment: Thanks eraserx.

Comment: and also if you want to go ahead and translate all the rashis on yirmiyahu chapter 52 that would be great, since that is the only chapter of yirmiyahu that doesn't have the rashis translated on chabad.org

Comment: You are welcome @johntessler. I don't have the time to translate all the Rashis there.  Perhaps your next question on Mi Yodeya should be "Where can I find a complete translation of Rashi on Yirmiyahu?".  I checked sefaria.org and they are also missing a translation on that chapter.

Comment: @EraserX I dont know where to find it either. Do you know or can you infer from reading it why Rashi's commentary is missing from that chapter but not others?

Comment: @ShipBuilding - Rashi's commentary is not missing from that chapter as it is present in the original Hebrew (on sefaria.org and chabad.org and many other sites).  What's missing there is an English translation.

Comment: @EraserX Well noted there with the specificity. It's been awhile since I was on here and made that comment, but probably from the context of the exchange being about the translation specifically, I would have responded in kind, but it's good practice to be as accurate and specific as possible so I appreciate you bringing that to my attention.

I'd still like to learn the answer as well though. By any chance do you know? Why did they include english translations for the other chapters but not this? Is it more controversial? Even so, would that make censoring it OK? It interrupts our learning.

Comment: @EraserX Correction: best case scenario it interrupts our learning. Worst case scenario, someone is unaware the translation is missing, and simply learns an inaccurate lesson that Rashi did not think that chapter warranted any commentary, and did not write any. 

So I am bringing two questions to learn from. One is why the translation is missing for certain chapters. The second is whether it is justified for sefaria to do that, or if others disagree and have a different practice of including all the translated chapters? Who poskims differently on this issue and who poskims same as sefaria?

Comment: @ShipBuilding - I suggest that you reach out to Sefaria at hello@sefaria.org - looks like there's more info on that here: https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/213949 - I have no connection to them and would not know why they would leave a section of translation out.  Things can sometimes happen by oversight, accident or computer glitch.